# stop slashes from displaying when echoing php string

Tags: php

I am using a PHP `$_GET` variable in my URL in PHP:

```
auth_code=QAJ-Z"YFl
```

but when i echo it in PHP `echo $_GET["auth_code"]` the slashes are still displaying before the any quotes

i tried using the PHP `stripslashes` function like this here:

`stripslashes($_GET["auth_code"])`

but its still displaying the slashes in the output on the page

i have checked and magic_quotes are currently OFF

Comment: It is completely unclear what you ask. If you are refering to the quotes character (`"`) in that string, then sure, since it is part of the string you will see it in the output. Why not? If you do not want that, then make sure it is not part of the string! Either by leaving it away in the URL or by means of a call to `str_replace()`. But that has nothing to do with "slashes", those would be / and \.

Comment: @arkascha is right, we don't see any `slash ( / )` there.  I can see  `hyphen( - )` and `quotes ( " )`; If you want to get rid of the quotes , you can try 

`$string = $_GET["auth_code"]; 
$newstring = str_replace('"', "", $string);`

Comment: the output has the slashes (`QAJ-Z\"YFl`)